# custom model update and insert all in one

Tags: php, codeigniter

When I insert/update a row I would like to be able to check if query update else will insert

I am not sure on how to make it so on my `($this->db->query())` if row exists `(website_id)` then it will be a update else will insert.

I use variable and foreach. Insert works fine but can not get the update to work. Currently each time I update it creates a new row. How am I able to make it use both so if insert will create new row else update the row belonging to the `website_id`

```
public function editSetting($group, $data, $website_id = 0) {
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    if (substr($key, 0, strlen($group)) == $group) {
            // Insert To Database Only
        if (!is_array($value)) {
            $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . $this->db->dbprefix . "setting SET 
            website_id = '" . (int)$website_id . "', `group` = " . $this->db->escape($group) .", 
            `key` = " . $this->db->escape($key) . ", 
            `value` = " . $this->db->escape($value) . " 
          ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: here is your deleted question core code: http://pastebin.com/ZWx0PEtu

Answer (score 1):

If you are using mysql as DB-Engine you can use:

```
INSERT INTO tablename (vars) VALUES (values)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE var1=value1, var2=value2;
```

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html for details.

Comment: You have example way it should?